# Mootools: How to keep elements highlighted onclick and stop all events?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, mootools, highlight

I'm building a map using HTML and Mootools. So far, I have managed to highlight each canton (state) on `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/undisclosedname/CdgJf/43/

I am now trying to add a click event which will keep the clicked canton (state) highlighted and bring up a small div with info about said canton (new element), locking the rest of the map until the aforementioned div is closed.

Basically I want to stop all events attached to `map#schweiz` and `ul#maplist` and its child elements (`mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, and click).

Could anyone please give me a clue on how it should be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to add an overlay that blocks all mouseover/mouseleave events.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/4WyYS/2/

Comment: MArc, thank you for your helpful reply. I thought of using a transparent image as overlay (karte-overlay.png), but couldn't figure out how to do it. I especially like your simple approach to ignoring events. Great lesson.

Comment: I changed the code a little to inject "lastInfo" relative to "mapContainer" rather than "page". Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4WyYS/8/